# Where can I get level 40 PvP gear?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I keep hearing people talk about Level 40 PvP gear but I cannot find which vendor sells it. On the fleet, the PvP vendors do not sell Level 40 PvP gear. Is it on a planet?

EDIT: I've found out that the vendors are on Dromund Kaas/Coruscant. I still can not find where the vendors are even though I know which planet it is on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are next to the appropriate Class Trainers on the capital worlds (below the Senate Plaza on Coruscant, and on the upper level of Kaas City on Dromund Kaas).